# How to check if two tables are identical as objects in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, database-administration

How can I check if two tables as objects are identical in Oracle?

I need to check below points for both tables.

1. Tables have the same number of columns with the same name, data type and length of the columns.
2. Both tables have the same number of the constraints respective to the columns.
3. Both tables have the same number of indexes and grants.

Both tables exist in the same schema.

Comment: You must list all the requirements for two tables to be "identical" in your business problem, you can't just list some of the requirements. ("Like, I want..." means this is not a complete list.) For example, you may require that the two table should be in the same schema and have the same name - in which case this is not possible; you can't have two tables with the same name in the same schema. So - do they have to be in the same schema? Do they have to have the same name (in which case you can't require for them to be in the same schema)? What do you actually mean by "identical"?

Comment: Both tables have not the same name, however exist  in same schema

Answer (score 2):

One way or another you have to query metadata. You can either

- select from user_tables/user_indexes/etc

or

- use dbms_metadata.(get_ddl|get_dependent_ddl|get_granted_ddl|etc) and compare text (or XML in case of get_xml etc). You may want to omit a lot of details while generating metadata by setting a lot of parameters like SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES to false using dbms_metadata.set_transform_param.

Another complexity is partitioned tables. Do you need them to have exactly the same partitions to be "identical"?

Even in very simple cases there may be subtle details. For example, do you consider below two tables "identical"?

```
create table t1 (id int, name varchar2(30), col int constraint chk_col check (col is not null));
create table t2 (id int, name varchar2(30), col int not null);
```

Column metadata differs

```
SQL> select table_name, column_name, nullable
  2  from user_tab_columns
  3  where table_name in ('T1','T2');

TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAM NULLABLE
---------- ---------- ----------
T1         ID         Y
T1         NAME       Y
T1         COL        Y
T2         ID         Y
T2         NAME       Y
T2         COL        N

6 rows selected.
```

So try to keep this reconciliation tool as simple as possible. It may have 3 outputs like identical/different/"requires manual comparison" so that you do not need to check each and every detail in your script.

PS. Some dev tools like Allround Automations PL/SQL developer have instruments for comparing metadata using UI.